# jQuery Id selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If I mouseenter on img with ID #ASC-01 I want to add class to li with same ID but with different path, is that possible to do this? I mean to write a path in braces, see the code.

```
    $(".pile img#ASC-01").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".option ul li#ASC-01").addClass("highlight_option");
});
```

thank you for any help

Comment: No, because you can't give the same id to multiple elements. The value of an id has to be unique across the entire page.

Comment: ok, thx for help, I will make an unique ID, but can I use a path method?

Comment: If you know an id value, then there's no need for anything else in the selector - because an id is unique!

Comment: Yup, I know that, but the question is if is possible to use a path (just want to know)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. (This isn't really a "JavaScript syntax" issue; it's about CSS selectors.) But anyway, sure, it's fine to use relationship operators in a selector involving an id, and sometimes it does make sense (like if you want to see if some known element is on the page in some certain way as opposed to some other way).

Comment: Thx, bro, that advice is really usefull to me :) thx a lot for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but it's not a good solution/approach to this problem. You can't have two elements with the same id in the DOM.

I would recommend you to do this way:

1. Instead of giving a duplicated id to your image, put an attribute
   referencing to the li object, like this:

   ```
   <img src="foo.jpg" imageFor="ASC-01">
   ```
2. And then on the trigger of your event, query for the li like this:

   ```
   $(".pile img").mouseenter(function(){
       imageLiFor = $(this).attr('imageFor');
       $("#"+imageLiFor).addClass("highlight_option");
       // Note that you don't need the ".option ul li" anymore because you have a unique id.
   });
   ```

So this way you can get rid of the duplicated id and also keep your code clean and understandable.

Hope i've helped. Have a nice day! :-)